# DevExtreme started to create unnecessary elements in TreeView

Tags: angular, devexpress, devextreme, devextreme-angular

After updating to DevExtreme 23.2 I confronted problem showe on screenshot

[image]

And this is what's expected to be seen

[image]

For some reason after updating to new version it creates blank expand element though the icons must be the root elements of the TreeView

[image]

This is the code that is used

```
<div class="menu-container">
  <dx-tree-view [items]="items"
                [keyExpr]="'key'"
                [selectionMode]="'single'"
                [focusStateEnabled]="false"
                [expandEvent]="'click'"
                [animationEnabled]="false"
                [height]="'100%'"
                [width]="'100%'"
                itemTemplate="itemTemplate"
                (onItemSelectionChanged)="onItemSelectionChanged()"
                (onItemExpanded)="onItemExpanded($event)"
                (onItemClick)="onItemClick($event)">
    <div *dxTemplate="let menuItem of 'itemTemplate'"
         [ngClass]="{
          'is-parent': menuItem.items && menuItem.items.length > 0
         }">
      <a (click)="onMenuItemClick($event)"
         [attr.href]="menuItem.route ? menuItem.route : null">
        <i *ngIf="menuItem.icon"
           class="dx-icon mdi mdi-{{menuItem.icon}}">
        </i>
        <span>{{menuItem.name}}</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    </dx-tree-view>
</div>
```